# Android stops XHR requests if many requests are made

Tags: android, angular, google-chrome, ionic-framework, capacitor

I have an App that uses ionic environment. I have sync for offline usage functionality for which I make a number of API calls on the backend but it gets canceled after few requests and my functionality is stopped.
The error, I get is related to CORS but I don't think it is a valid error.
Can anyone tell me after how many requests it stops making new ones?
Or what can I do to prevent this behavior?

Comment: CORS is server related issue. enable CORS on your server.

Comment: CORS is enabled it is cancelled by chrome on Android as it works well on safari.

Comment: Added domain in network.xml file and set in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Comment: @RaviAshara, can you please provide more details.

Comment: android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" added in android -> app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml file application tag.

create new file with `network_security_config.xml` and add in android -> app -> src -> res -> xml folder.

Comment: And add this code in `network_security_config.xml` file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>set domain here</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
 <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
  <trust-anchors>
   <certificates src="system" />
  </trust-anchors>
 </base-config>
</network-security-config>